# How many rows/documents can I load in memory?

Tags: node.js, database

It may be a strange question, but I've been always interested in how to work with database correctly, especially how many rows/documents I can load in memory to process them.

For example, I have small rows, with 5 fields. Each field takes up to 5 characters (`utfmb4`). I use `Node.JS` to work with the database.

So, the questions are:

**How many rows can I load from the database in memory to process them?**

**What do I need to take into account in such situations?**

Answer (score 0):

In general, your limitation is a number of available RAM on the machine. So if you use JS to process data each 5 character string will use 5 * 16 bit (2 bytes) memory. Divide available RAM memory by size of word * 5, and you will receive the approximate amount of rows.